# How to install necessary packages by `npm install`

Tags: npm

I have the following in package.json.

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.8.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "laravel-elixir": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

After running `npm install` when I check node_modules, there are a lot of packages are installed. from .bin, abbrev to yeast. I think there are more than 200 packages. I thought npm installs only necessary packages including dependencies.

Q1: How can I avoid installing unnecessary packages and installing only necessary packages. Can I do it? Or do I need all packages?

Q2: Does `npm install` all npm packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Summary:**

> Q1: How can I avoid installing unnecessary packages and installing
>   only necessary packages. Can I do it? Or do I need all packages?

You are installing all dependencies required by the dependencies of your module (modules requiring modules).

> Q2: Does npm install all npm packages?

No.

**In depth:**

You installed gulp. Here are gulp's dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "archy": "^1.0.0",
    "chalk": "^1.0.0",
    "deprecated": "^0.0.1",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.0",
    "interpret": "^1.0.0",
    "liftoff": "^2.1.0",
    "minimist": "^1.1.0",
    "orchestrator": "^0.3.0",
    "pretty-hrtime": "^1.0.0",
    "semver": "^4.1.0",
    "tildify": "^1.0.0",
    "v8flags": "^2.0.2",
    "vinyl-fs": "^0.3.0"
  }
```

archy has the following dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "ansi-styles": "^2.1.0",
    "escape-string-regexp": "^1.0.2",
    "supports-color": "^3.1.2"
  },
```

interpret (still going through gulp dependencies) has the following dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "extend": "^2.0.1",
    "findup-sync": "^0.3.0",
    "flagged-respawn": "^0.3.1",
    "rechoir": "^0.6.0",
    "resolve": "^1.1.6"
  }
```

liftoff has the following dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "extend": "^2.0.1",
    "findup-sync": "^0.3.0",
    "flagged-respawn": "^0.3.1",
    "rechoir": "^0.6.0",
    "resolve": "^1.1.6"
  }
```

orchestrator requires the following dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "end-of-stream": "~0.1.5",
    "sequencify": "~0.0.7",
    "stream-consume": "~0.1.0"
  },
```

...

In short... The bigger, more dependent module you install, the more dependencies are required. It's not always a bad thing. I recommend installing only what is needed to get the job you need done (sometimes it's a lot, sometimes not).

**UPDATE**

I just noticed that gulp was a dev-dependency... Moving on to elixir non-dev dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.7.10",
    "browserify": "^11.2.0",
    "del": "^1.2.0",
    "glob": "^5.0.14",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^2.3.1",
    "gulp-babel": "^6.1.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "gulp-batch": "^1.0.5",
    "gulp-coffee": "^2.3.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-cssnano": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-if": "^1.2.5",
    "gulp-less": "^3.0.3",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "gulp-notify": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-phpspec": "^0.5.3",
    "gulp-phpunit": "0.11.x",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-rev": "^5.1.0",
    "gulp-rev-replace": "^0.4.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.3",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.5.2",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.5.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.4.2",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.6",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.2.4",
    "insert-css": "^0.2.0",
    "merge-stream": "^0.1.8",
    "parse-filepath": "^0.5.0",
    "partialify": "^3.1.3",
    "path": "^0.11.14",
    "require-dir": "^0.3.0",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.1",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3",
    "underscore-deep-extend": "0.0.5",
    "vinyl-buffer": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-paths": "^1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "^1.1.0",
    "watchify": "^3.2.3"
  },
```

...